# Post mostly code. How can I edit it?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

When I tried editing a post, I received this message:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

This shouldn't be the case, as firstly it isn't my post, and the editor cannot really add much more details. Especially when the code is so long, it is hard to add more information to counter this warning message.

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230457/how-can-i-redirect-user-to-my-first-page-after-login-is-verified-and-remove-hide)

Comment: There is a header and then the code starts: `**app.py**`  add a white line after the header so the codeblock is separated from any surrounding text, move the import that follows the code fence to the next line. Maybe it needs a paragraph of text before the image.

Comment: Regarding "as firstly it isn't my post", I've asked about this on Meta SE: [Shouldn't it be "this post" instead of "your post" while editing someone else's post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362331/shouldnt-it-be-this-post-instead-of-your-post-while-editing-someone-elses)

Comment: *"Especially when the code is so long"* that's part of the problem; the OP should be making a MRE, not posting *all* of their code.